# Open and CheckOut a presentation using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, powerpoint

I open and immediately CheckOut a PowerPoint presentation from an Intranet server with a PowerPoint macro:

```vb
Sub Open_n_CheckOut()    
    Presentations.CheckOut FileName:="Link"    
    Presentations.Open FileName:="Link"    
End Sub
```

I would prefer to do the operation from an Excel workbook instead of a separate PowerPoint file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work:

```
Sub Open_PPT()

Dim PPT As Object
Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

With PPT.Presentations
    If .CanCheckOut("link") = True then
        .CheckOut Filename:="link"
        .Open Filename:="link"
        PPT.Visible = True
    Else
        PPT.Quit
        Msgbox "Can't checkout presentation at this moment!"
    End if
End With

End Sub
```

Would you wish to check back in, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/presentation-checkin-method-powerpoint) might be a starting point.

Surely try to catch any error, as I'm unsure if this would work (untested)

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps a lot.

Comment: @TyRa97, does it work for you? Also, edited the answer a bit to only show PPT when `.CanCheckOut = True`. If this has answered your question please consider to mark this answer as helpfull and answered.

Comment: Yeah it worked very well for me. But I have two questions: Is there a book or something where I can learn about VBA Excel connection to the other office applications? And the same method doesn't work for checking the presentation back in and closing it. Do you have advice on doing that?

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/controlling-one-microsoft-office-application-from-another) is a link that covers the basics. Just search the net for more in depth one like [this](http://what-when-how.com/excel-vba/interacting-with-other-office-applications-via-excel-vba/) one. About the `.CheckIn Filename:="link"`... it depends what you want while the file is open, what you expect your code to do and what error occurs. For now I'll add a link in the answer that covers checkin back in.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thank you very much for the links. It is very important to me to improve in VBA, thanks :). Regarding the CheckIn I basically tried to use the same Framework as for the CheckOut but I get the message: "Object does not support this property of method".
In essence I want to have a macro that ChecksIn an Active Presentation which is open. Thank you in advance.